# jQuery invalid label jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I use jQuery to get php-script result with ajax-function. Problem is php-script is on the another domain, so I should use "jsonp" as returned dataType, BUT php-script returns json, not jsonp (maybe script is not correct) and I get syntax error. How can I handle it? I suppose, that I can somehow get json string before ajax-function handles it and rises error, is it possible?

This is my ajax function:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://www.pecom.ru/bitrix/components/pecom/calc/ajax.php",
        data: res,
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("error: " + xhr.status);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data)
        }
    }
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: could you post your PHP code too?

Comment: It is not my code and I cant change it.. Only with firebug I can see, that it returns "{ param : something, ... }", not "callback({ param : something, ... })"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

The longer one is that you have to set up some sort of proxying: make the request on the server side from a machine you control, transform the results to proper JSONP there, and connect to that server via AJAX.
(Or, in the very unlikely event that the target server supports [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/), you can use that instead of JSONP.)